# Split phone numbers into groups based on first digit

Tags: formatting, number

#### Problem

I am trying to split some numbers based on some very simple criteria. Numbers with `8` digits starting with **4**, **8** or **9** should be split into digit groups of length `3 2 3`.

Any other digit of length 8 should be split into groups of two.

Numbers with less digits than 8 should not be split into groups.

#### Examples

> - 23 27 60 11 (hard spaces)
> - 404 43 033 (hard spaces, 3 2 3)
> - 820 43 033 (hard spaces, 3 2 3)
> - 909 64 159 (hard spaces)
> - 07979 (no spaces)
> - 110 (no spaces), 112 (no spaces), 113 (no spaces)

Sorry for the lack of MWE, but I am not quite sure where to start.

Comment: What about numbers with more than 8 digits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with the `xstring` package, which provides commands for extracting and comparing substrings.

It is possible to do some preprocessing to the string before the formatting is applied, for example to remove whitespace. The `xstring` commands for extracting substrings, modifications and counts have the general syntax `\Command{arg1}{...}[\result]` where the optional `\result` argument stores the result for further processing (if this argument is not given the result is just printed directly). This can be used for preprocessing to store the preprocessed string and do the rest of the processing on the result string.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifstartnum
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\splitdigits}[1]{%
\StrDel{#1}{ }[\newstring]%
\StrLen{\newstring}[\mylen]%
\ifnum \mylen=8 %
\startnumfalse%
\IfBeginWith{\newstring}{4}{\startnumtrue}{}%
\IfBeginWith{\newstring}{8}{\startnumtrue}{}%
\IfBeginWith{\newstring}{9}{\startnumtrue}{}%
\ifstartnum%
\StrLeft{\newstring}{3}\ \StrMid{\newstring}{4}{5}\ \StrRight{\newstring}{3}%
\else%
\StrLeft{\newstring}{2}\ \StrMid{\newstring}{3}{4}\ \StrMid{\newstring}{5}{6}\ \StrRight{\newstring}{2}%
\fi%
\else%
#1%
\fi%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent\splitdigits{23276011}\\
\splitdigits{40443033}\\
\splitdigits{82043033}\\
\splitdigits{90964159}\\
\splitdigits{07979}\\
\splitdigits{110} \splitdigits{112} \splitdigits{113}\\
\splitdigits{9 09 6415 9}\\
\splitdigits{90 96 41 59}\\
\splitdigits{232 76 011}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Is it possible to also handle inputs such at `\splitdigits{9 09 6415 9}` and `\splitdigits{90 96 41 59}`, `\splitdigits{232 76 011}`?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar that is possible, you can delete all spaces before you format the numbers using `\StrDel`. See page 8 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/xstring/xstring-en.pdf#page=9).

Comment: @Marjin Thanks! But I still can not make it work. Writing

`\def\newnum{\StrDel{400 7519}{ }}

\newnum

\splitdigits{\newnum}`

Does not work as it expands too late.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar the idea is to do the preprocessing inside of the command, see edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried to do as you did but with `\newcommand{\newstring}[1]{\StrDel{#1}{ }}` is the problem with this approach that the result expands too late?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem is, but the `\StrDel` command itself is composed of a lot of code that you should avoid passing around too much. The way to do this is to use the built-in optional command, i.e., `\StrDel{#1}{ }[\newstring]` which does the same thing as you try to do with `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 2):

Branch according to the length of the argument: if it is eight digit long, branch with respect to the first digit; otherwise print the argument.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\phone}{m}
 {
  \nebu_phone:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \nebu_phone:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:n { #1 } = 8 }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_eight:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    #1
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
   {
    {4}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {8}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {9}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
   }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn #1
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2#3\nobreakspace#4#5\nobreakspace#6#7#8 }
\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2\nobreakspace#3#4\nobreakspace#5#6\nobreakspace#7#8 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\phone{23276011}

\phone{40443033}

\phone{82043033}

\phone{90964159}

\phone{07979}

\phone{110}, \phone{112}, \phone{113}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to remove spaces from the input, you have to give up expandability:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\phone}{m}
 {
  \nebu_phone:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__nebu_phone_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nebu_phone:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { #1 }
  \tl_remove_all:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { ~ }
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:N \l__nebu_phone_tl = 8 }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_eight:V \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
   {
    {4}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {8}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {9}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
   }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn #1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n { V }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2#3\nobreakspace#4#5\nobreakspace#6#7#8 }
\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2\nobreakspace#3#4\nobreakspace#5#6\nobreakspace#7#8 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\phone{232 76 011}

\phone{40 44 30 33}

\phone{820 430 33}

\phone{90964159}

\phone{079 79}

\phone{110}, \phone{112}, \phone{113}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.